# Color of active link on blue background Image here in Meta SE, makes it less visible

Tags: feature-request, design, navigation

Today I signed up for Meta SE and first thing that made uneasy to use was the color of the active link on blue background image. Can it me improved or changed if someone else also think the same?

[image]